# D3 using classed() to add and remove class with checkbox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, checkbox

I am having trouble removing a class that I have added using a checkbox. The checkbox is checked to begin with. When it is unchecked by the user it adds a "hideRect" class with classed('hideRect', true); 
this works great BUT when I check the box again the class doesn't go away.

Here is my code:

```
this.$node.append('input')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
    .attr('checked', true)
    .attr('value', 'med')
    .on('click', () => this.updateRectLine());
  }

private updateRectLine() {

  //var rect = this.$node.getElementsByClassName('.MEDICATION');
  var cbMed = this.$node.attr("checked");
  if (cbMed !== true){
      this.$node.selectAll(".MEDICATION").classed('hideRect', true);
  }

  else if (cbMed == true){
      this.$node.selectAll(".MEDICATION").classed('hideRect', false);
  }
```

}

thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the relationship between the elements w/ class `.MEDICATION` and the checkbox? On the first line of your function, try logging the value of that selection to see if it includes the elements you expect it to.

Comment: Hey @anbnyc thanks for the reply! I can see the class added to the right element in the console so I know it targets the right selection but it wont remove the class!

Comment: Can't think of what else might be the problem. If you can provide a reproducible example (like a JSFiddle) might be able to tell more. This probably isn't related, but you may want triple equals (`cbMed === true`) to check after the `else if`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to update the below function like this

```
private updateRectLine() { 
  var cbMed = this.$node.select("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked");
  if (!cbMed)
    this.$node.selectAll(".MEDICATION").classed('hideRect', true);
  else
    this.$node.selectAll(".MEDICATION").classed('hideRect', false);
}
```

`.attr()` function only returns the value the checkbox was initialized to, to check for a checkbox's check state, you want to use property `checked` present on check box elements

Comment: even:
    this.$node.selectAll(".MEDICATION").classed('hideRect', cbMed);

Comment: @WEBCENTER What you had was the best way to write that line of code, I just used the code from the original post, and changed `attr` to `prop`, but thanks for the tip

Comment: Yes, I know, but not everyone know / remember about short if;) (like me;p)